# Responsive in bootstrap3

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a default css of images responsiveness of height in bootstrap 3. I know i have to include the class of `img-responsive` but only the width was responsive.

`<ims src = "images/blablabla" class = "img-responsive">`

I am searching through net but cant find what I am looking for. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

The width image will be respond to the size of your col, depending what you assign to (col-lg-3 or 4, 5 ..).
The height of the image will adjust accordingly with the width of the image.

I'm not quite sure what your application is.  You may want to size your images in photoshop before hand.

Comment: Thankz I figure it out, i had set a fixed height so it will not resize if the user resize the browser..